# Lenovo G50-70 Microphone Doesn't work with Skype/Hangouts on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, lenovo, skype, microphone

I have not tried this on other versions of Ubuntu, I tried calling through Skype and Hangouts, but the problem persisted- No Sound was emmited.
I increased the values of the input device tab and the recording tab in Pulse Audio Control(pavucontrol), I also tried with alsamixer. Nothing really worked until I tried disballancing the left and right channels of the microphone (which seems to be a stereo one), I did it also in alsamixer with"Q" and "E".
Afterwards everything seems to work fine in both methods, but the question is:

Can I set this disballance by default after restart so I don't have to manually set it every start-up?

Comment: I have the same issue on a G50-45. Hope it gets more attention. Haven't tried disbalancing the values yet. Will try.

Comment: Have you tried to press "Set as fallback" before close the pavucontrol window?
It seems to be permanently fixed in my case :)